# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action

Tags: development, web-part, csom

Currently I'm started learning CSOM (C#). 
I have created web part in **Farm Solution**. and deploy on local site. 
Web part is use for display Web title.

It shows error on line 
`context.ExecuteQuery();`

**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**

[image]

I'm using this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) article

Please suggest some answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set credential to your context as the following

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://PC5/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    //your code 
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: M.Qassas. It's working for me. may be I'm wrong, Is it bad practice to pass credentials from web part?

Comment: Is that reason for not to use CSOM in Web Part. because I had mostly work on server object

Comment: Why it's bad?!, you need to define the context credential, to avoid access denied! however, the best practice is to define this credential as key in web config and read it as mentioned at http://www.codenotation.com/2011/12/sharepoint-2010-webconfig-read-and.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this:

```
string siteUrl = args.Length < 2 ? "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/customsite/" : args[0];
            string userName = args.Length < 2 ? "abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" : args[1];
            string password = args.Length < 2 ? "password" : args[2];



            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }

                context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

                Web oWeb = context.Web;
                context.Load(oWeb, website => website.Title);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Comment: I'm not using  sandbox solution , its simply Farm solution. so your code still work for Web part on local farm